# ¿Cómo evitar el mensaje Bad Request Too Long en una aplicación web?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en asp.net c#  ,con ayuda de Entity Framework para registrar y actualizar datos,me he topado con el siguiente problema:

Al utilizar el método de actualización por más de 10 veces consecutivas,es decir actualizar los datos de diversos registros me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que utilizo para actualizar es el siguiente,me ha funcionado sin problemas:

```
protected void Actualizar(int id){
     tblpersonas actualizar = ctx.tblpersonas.Where(x => x.id== id).FirstOrDefault();
      actualizar.nombre= txtnombre.text,
      actualizar.domicilio= txtdomicilio.text,
      ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

En el Web Config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
```

El problema solo aparece al actualizar datos.
Lo soluciono temporalmente borrando el historial del navegador Google Chrome, pero más tarde vuelve a generarse.
¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?